# below is my code i want to send the image url to server not the complete image by using below code i am getting server 500 error in android studio

Tags: android

Is okhttp is good for this or do you have any code similar to this ping me

Comment: post more code please to clarify

Comment: If you get an http status 500 back from the server then you need to check the servers error log file for what the actual issue is...

Comment: the server accepts only the url i am unable to send URL

Comment: thank you for your respoce i posted my complete code bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Posting Data To server By Get Method

public void sendingDataToServer(){

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("onResponseSuccess", response.toString() + "check");

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("onResponseSuccess", error.toString() + "check");

    }
       }) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; ");
        headers.put("x-oc-Image-url", "Your Image Path Url");
        try {
            headers.putAll(super.getHeaders());
        } catch (AuthFailureError authFailureError) {
            authFailureError.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.getHeaders();
    }
};
Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext).add(stringRequest);
```

}

Comment: thankyou bro for your valuble time ill try to implement this

Comment: what is            header .put  headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; ");
                        headers.put("x-oc-Image-url", "Your Image Path Url");

Comment: Ask back end developer how he need the request by header format or Json Object format

Comment: he told thathe need by URL only

Comment: Procedure one
1. String url ="Ypur Server Url "+"/" +"Your Image Url ";
2. If It's on Header format 
     Header Parameter Name

Comment: URL which i send as an image it should look like this https://www.jagranimages.com/images/27_07_2015-27tom-cruise.jpg

Comment: thankyou for helping me this much pls can u get me your mail id ill send you the complete code so that you can add what is wrong

Comment: aravind.v234@gmail.com

Comment: i sent you my full code and i uploaded in the same page to pls verify and let me know

Answer (score 0):

If Your Sending Only Url to server there are ways to send Image Url to server
1. Passing through Header 
2. Passing through JsonObject

I Suspect their is not posting Image Url path in your code.

In Server Side 500 error means request parameter not receiving to server time you will get this error.

Comment: can u refer me to any code if you have so that i can get an idea of how to do it i am new to android so pls